# Ho to print PDO results in a while loop but from a user specified index and not from start?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, while-loop

I have a database result set created from a PDO object.
The array contains all the data. Now I want to print the results but I want to start the printing from a specific index and not from the start.The start index is specified from a user. Please don't tell me to modify the query because this is not what I want. Also I've searched everywhere and didn't found any solutions to this. 
I simplified my code so it's more understandable and easier to come to the point.
Thanks for any-kind of help. :>)

```
$res2=$conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blogs");
$res2->execute();
 while($r=$res2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
 // I have 37 records in $res2 and want to start echoing from record number 10.
//for example I want to echo out $r['title'] but not from the first but from the 5th or 10th index.

}
```

Comment: Such a eagle eye @Fred-ii- !!!

Comment: @Saty *Awk! Awk!* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- no it's not type. I will access the fields with $r['fieldname'].

Comment: Add a counter, then add an if statement: `if($i > 9) {echo stuff}`

Comment: @Fred-ii- my bad. sorry I edited it :-)

Comment: You should modify your query adding LIMIT clause.

Comment: OP clearly states he does not want to modify the query @YourCommonSense

Comment: @YourCommonSense I know this and I have seen it in one of your answers here. But I don't want to modify my query as Jay Blanchard said.Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the DV @YourCommonSense. Watched your score go down after the vote, so know it was you. 101,017 > 101,016.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You're not very nice and downvoting Jay's answer (FACT and NOT FICTION). You ought to be ashamed of yourself, you know that? You're pathetic.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Let him, it's all the fun he ever gets.

Comment: @Fred-ii- instead of concerning about Jay's downvotes please remove the downvotes on my questions. :)

Comment: @DevMan I removed mine a LONG time ago. Ask that common "whatever" to do it.  Downvoting questions/answers seems to be a national pastime over there. You should be concerned about Jay being downvoted by that guy. If anything, I upvoted it (your question) lol et voila.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I know I also didn't like that because Jay gave me a really nice and practical answer. What can I say about people making things personal? :(

Comment: @DevMan Plus, you shouldn't be accusing people (me for instance) until you know 100% for sure because that may affect you later on (I'm trying to help you out here). And that YCS... it's 100% sure that he downvoted Jay's answer; *fact* ;-)

Comment: It's all good - I don't concern myself with guys like that. Karma will do its thing.

Comment: *There you go Sam* @JayBlanchard You are one of the best guys here (on earth) ;-)

Comment: *Thanks Ralph!* You too @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't accuse you but I didn't know who I should tell this. And the only guy who was talking the right way was you. I commented on you so maybe others who DVed me can read and remove. Sorry for that.

Comment: @DevMan *"instead of concerning about Jay's downvotes please remove the downvotes on my questions."* and you pinged me. Errr... I'd call that an accusation *lol* - No worries, I won't hold it against you. I have a sense of humour and patience. I grow "cactus" after all; I have to be ;-) I'm glad that you got your solution and that Jay was able to help you out. *Cheers* - Edit: Ok, I see what you meant now. No problema, tutto bene mi amico! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `if()` statement and a counter:

```
$userInput = 5;
$i = 0;
while($r=$res2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
    if($i >= $userInput){
         // echo your output here
    } 
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure it's pretty easy and I knew this. If there is no way to do it with predefined functions than this would be the only efficient way to do it. Thanks

Comment: There is no predefined function for this @DevMan, but you could write a function.